# Autodesk plant 3D database quey with left join keeps giving Null values

Tags: sql, mysql, autocad

For a project I am trying  to combine fields from two tables from an Autodesk plant 3D database file (piping.dcf). I would like to get fields from EngineeringItems and PnpTegRegistry (Both have PnPID as key fields). If I run selection queries on both table separately (select * from) it runs correctly, but when I try to use LEFT JOIN it keeps giving me Null values for all files from PnpTegRegistry.

The fieldnames are pre-defined in the database

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
select  EngineeringItems_PNP.PnPID,
        EngineeringItems_PNP.PartFamilyLongDesc, 
        EngineeringItems_PNP.Manufacturer,
        PnPTagRegistry.PnPID,
        PnPTagRegistry.Tag
from EngineeringItems_PNP
left join PnPTagRegistry on EngineeringItems_PNP.PnPID=PnPTagRegistry.PnPID;
```

Comment: "...it keeps giving me Null values for all files from PnpTegRegistry..." -- Are there any rows in `PnpTegRegistry` that match the predicate `EngineeringItems_PNP.PnPID = PnPTagRegistry.PnPID`?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, EngineeringItems_PNP.PnPID has no direct relation with PnPTagRegistry.PnPID, but with PnPTagRegistry.RowId

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).